# Apache Nutch-2.2.1 installation

Tags: nutch

I am installing nutch2.2.1 on my centOS virtual machine and getting an error injecting the seed urls(directory name). I used this command:

```
/usr/share/apache-nutch-2.1/src/bin/nutch inject root/apache-nutch-2.1/src/testresources/testcrawl urls
```

And i got an error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob
```

Similarly, for the command

```
/usr/share/apache-nutch-2.1/src/bin/nutch readdb
```

gives me an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.WebTableReader
```

What should i do to fix these errors?
I am following the tutorial from: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial and followed the same steps as suggested.

Also my query also revolves around setting the path for ant. Every time i open a new session i have to set the ANT_HOME and PATH environment variable manually. And then they work all fine. Same is the case with setting JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I wrote an article couple of years ago with full details how to setup Nutch 2. For people stopping by may find it useful - http://abdulmunim.com/configure-nutch-2-with-hbase/

Answer (score 0):

You should go to $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/ directory to run the the commands.

Comment: That is where i was running the commands. Anyway thanks for the help. The problem is somewhat related to the server's configuration.